# GCP Slack error reporting is not working anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, slack, error-reporting

Slack integration for error reporting suddenly stopped working. Anyone experienced similar issues?

We also removed the slack channel integration and redid it. Sadly no improvement. Also worth noting is, that other channels work as expected

Comment: We also identified the same problem since Sunday. As a workaround - especially to not miss your errors - you can setup an alert policy for 5xx HTTP status codes via https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies/create.

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui

Comment: They are looking into it: https://twitter.com/kyleabenson/status/1590357649094475776